# Features phone vs Smartphone: can features phone run Web based application?

Tags: html, web-applications, smartphone

i was reading an article about smartphones and features phones, and i was surprised to see that smartphones share only the 28% of the global MArket. In Africa, Asia, South American and so on there are still plenty of featured phones.....Than thanks to Java platform and Brew can run just a few third part made applications.

Now i was also reading another article about native app vs Web applications. Web application are crossplatform and thaks to html5 the gap between them and native apps is gonna be smaller.
My question is, Can features phone (or at least a part of them) run Web applications? SO Web applications are actually targeting also features phone........You just need a browser to run web app, do they have it? And are they gonna support html5 or only html4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the phrase "Feature phones" has no exact definition.  All it really means is that they have less capabilities than "smart phones", but more capabilities than a "simple phone".

One of the capabilities that a smart phone is usually better at is the quality of the browser.  Feature phones usually have a less full-featured browser that will likely not support much of HTML5 and usually be somewhat behind the capabilities of a recent smartphone as they are usually trying to work with smaller memory and a slower processor.

Plus, you can generally expect smaller screens and more limited user interaction making it more difficult to interact with a web app.

Comment: Tnx, so according to your answer SOME features phone could be able to run simple html4 applications, isn't it? So the real answer is not  simply Yes or No, but maybe, is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to build web applications for feature phone browsers, they would have to be incredibly basic.  In my experience, feature phone browsers don't even fully support HTML4.  Maybe they've changed since I last had a feature phone, but web browsing in general was almost pointless on my old feature phone.  Web pages looked horrible, connection speeds were horrible (less than 3G), and the screen was way too small.  Any web applications built for feature phones would have to pretty much be text-only to be usable.

Answer (score 0):

Nokia Asha series support web app. Though they are not smartphone but can work like them except some features.